# My edit should not have been approved

Tags: discussion

I made an edit prior to carefully reading [here](https://health.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/411). Before anyone one approved it, I edited the summary to say REJECT EDIT but **none** of the reviewers read my message.

If you are going to review, **do not** be a robo reviewer. Double check the suggestions and for the other review task please do the same too.

This isn't really a question but a public service announcement.

[Here](https://health.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/412) is another example of **NOT** reading the edit. My first edit incorrectly introduce the [common-cold](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/common-cold) which was an error and my fault. The edit shouldn't have been allowed. I then tried to correct my error by restoring the original tag but it was rejected.

Comment: No matter the comment that comes with the edit if the edit itself is valid. The comment is just there in case of doubt, no?

Comment: @Shlublu my edit was mistake and should have never been approved. The comment was there letting them know not to approve it.

Comment: @dustin I thought your comment about rejecting was referring to the [previous edit](http://health.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/410), which wasn't right, so I did what you said - rejected it. And logically I've seen your another edit which indicated that it's another better version of the edit. So it wasn't a robo reviewing, but confusion of two different edits in a row and what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: @kenorb your reject of that edit is incorrect too.

Comment: @dustin -  Am I understanding this correctly? You suggested an edit. You added a comment in your "briefly explain" comment box, but then didn't cancel the edit (instead submitted it), and It was voted on. Is that accurate?  FWIW, I agree people should be careful editors. This question was, however, particularly confusing.

Comment: @anongoodnurse suggested edit, submitted, realized it was incorrect, and edit the comment box before anyone reviewed it. However, the reviewers didn't pay attention and approved a wrong edit.

Comment: @dustin - the error is fixed.